# Illegal XML character

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following table row:

```
<tr id="trInbox" runat="server" class="normal"
  style='cursor:pointer; font-weight:<%# StyleBold(Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("inbRead")) ) %>'
  onclick='selectedRow(this,<%# Eval("INBID") %>)'
  onMouseOver="if(this.className!='selected') this.style.backgroundColor='#E2E1F4';"
  onMouseOut="if(this.className!='selected') this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'">
```

But, after I run this, I get the following error:

> illegal XML character [Break On This Error]
>
> selectedRow(this,<%# Eval("INBID") %>)

Can you tell me what syntax am I missing?

Comment: What is the value of `INBID` when you get the error?

Answer (score 1):

When running elements server side, its best to use [`String.Format()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) when adding attribute values containing dynamic data. Try:

```
<tr id="trInbox" runat="server" class="normal" style='<%# String.Format("cursor:pointer; font-weight:{0}", StyleBold(Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("inbRead")))) %>' onclick='<%# String.Format("selectedRow(this,{0})", Eval("INBID")) %>' onMouseOver="if(this.className!='selected') this.style.backgroundColor='#E2E1F4';" onMouseOut="if(this.className!='selected') this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing a ";" at backgroundColor style, in onMouseOut.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the selectedRow method does some processing that involves object (de)serialization or converting a Xml string  to a Xml document.

Some characters are illegal : http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets

You should check your Xml String to remove any invalid character.

Here is an example of utility method to check if a character is valid :

```
    public static bool IsValidCharForXml(char x)
    {
        return x == (char)0x9
                  || x == (char)0xA
                  || x == (char)0xD
                  || (x >= (char)0x20 && x <= (char)0xD7FF)
                  || (x >= (char)0xE000 && x <= (char)0xFFFD);
    }
```